# Formik and Yup conditional validation not working with useState

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik, yup

I am using React Native with Expo, and am working in IOS currently.

Using Formik and Yup, I am trying to conditionally validate a form,

Here is the form.js

```
import {Formik} from 'formik'
import { newApptSchema } from '../FormValidation'

const NewAppt = ({ navigation }) => {

    
    //These are the values that formik and yup will check
    const apptForm = {
        
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        
        spouseFirstName: '',
        spouseLastName: '',
        
        etc...
    }
const [hasSpouse, sethasSpouse] = useState(false);

return (
            <Formik
                //Prevents a dumb glitch
                enableReinitialize
                //validates based on the Form Validation Schema
                validationSchema={newApptSchema}
                initialValues={apptForm}
                //Prevents Errors from popping up as they type
                validateOnChange={false}
                onSubmit={(values, actions)=>(
                    console.log(SubmitNewAppt()),
                    SubmitNewAppt(values),
                    navigation.navigate('Appointments')
                )}
            >
            {(props)=> (
            <>
            <Text style={styles.lableText}>Do you have a Spouse?</Text>
            <Switch 
                    onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
                    value={hasSpouse}
                    />
            { hasSpouse ? <>
                    <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                        <View style={{flex:1}}>
                            <TextInput  
                            value={props.values.spouseFirstName}
                            placeholder='Spouse First Name'
                            onChangeText={props.handleChange('spouseFirstName')}/> 
                        </View>
                        <View style={{flex:1}}>
                            <TextInput 
                            value={props.values.spouseLastName} 
                            placeholder='Spouse Last Name'
                            onChangeText={props.handleChange('spouseLastName')}> 
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    { props.errors.spouseFirstName || props.errors.spouseLastName ? <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                        <View style={{flex:1}}>
                            <Text style={styles.errorText}>Test</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{flex:1}}>
                            <Text style={styles.errorText}>{ props.errors.spouseLastName }</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View> : null }
                    </>: null}
            </>
            )}
            </Formik>
    )
}

export default NewAppt
```

and here is my FormValidation.js

```
import * as Yup from 'yup'


//This file is used for all form validations across the app

//exporting the validation schemas to be used in formik forms across the app
export const newApptSchema = Yup.object({
    hasSpouse: Yup.boolean(),
    spouseFirstName: Yup.string()
        .when("hasSpouse", {
        is: true,
        then: Yup.string()
        .required("First Name is required")
        .min(3, '3 Character Min')
    }),
    spouseLastName: Yup.string()
    .when("hasSpouse", {
        is: true,
        then: Yup.string()
        .required("Last Name is required")
        .min(3, '3 Character Min')
    }),
    Phone2: Yup.string()
    .when("hasSpouse", {
        is: true,
        then: Yup.string()
        .matches('^((\\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \\-]*)|(\\([0-9]{2,3}\\)[ \\-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \\-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \\-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$', 'Phone number is not valid')
    })
})
```

When "hasSpouse" is true, it should require spouseFirstName and spouseLastName, and validate Phone2, but for some reason it will go through without those even when hasSpouse has been toggled 'True'.  It also will not throw the expected errors.

I've gone into the Yup git and NPM pages, but can't find the documentation for .when, I've only learned about it through Stack.

I assume I'm missing something dumb and somehow 'hasSpouse' is false in the validation schema, but I'm at a loss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: change new solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `Switch`  value does not affect Formik's `hasSpouse` value.

Refactor code as below

```js
<Switch
  onValueChange={(value) => {
    props.setFieldValue("hasSpouse", value);
  }}
  value={props.values.hasSpouse}
/>;
```

Comment: Gotcha, should I add it in as false to the initial values instead of the state value?

Comment: Yes. Add to initial value like other form values